# Creating Image Gallery using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create thumbnail image gallery in CSS, and if I click on any thumbnail, the image needs to open in a popup in bigger size (Background layer will be darkened). Images attached for reference.

Is it possible to create this gallery by using pure CSS scripting itself?...or with the help of Javascript.  I am a beginner to CSS and Javascript coding so please suggest me the simple and best methodology.

**Image Gallery**
[image: Image Gallery]

**Image Popup Window**
[image: Image Popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is solution such as [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) or [lightbox](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) who help you to do this kind of thing with javascript.

And there is also pure CSS solution, according to MDN [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget) and [demo](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4607/lightbox.html#).

Comment: Thanks JBR for your valuable solutions. Sure will go through each link and try to workout the best. Thanks!